# Should I still edit closed/bad posts to make them presentable?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

Sometimes we get [not perfect posts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/how-to-create-a-design-for-winforms-that-is-dynamic) that are immediately close-worthy *and* have pretty poor grammar. Normally I swoop in to keep people's English presentable, but should I do it for not-so-good closed posts as well?

I want to keep the site as presentable as possible but at the same time dedicating such effort to posts that are more than borderline closable seems dubious.

Comment: Fix them if they're probably staying, don't bother if they will soon be deleted.

Comment: My bad for not reading very well nor following the link you provided, so let me stress that **the above is referring to posts that will probably never be reopened again, but might still be visible on the site for some time**. (Right?)

Comment: @Arjan yeah, that's my problem. This post is going to be on UX's front page for a couple days probably. Doesn't feel right just outright deleting it though since the user should be able to learn from their mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If doing so will aid in resurrecting the question (i.e. getting it reopened), then I think it's worth it.  But not for unrecoverable posts.  If the posts eventually get deleted anyway, your effort is wasted.

Comment: Also, I feel that badly formatted/written posts that ask/rant about why things were closed, or about why one is question banned, or about why one cannot ask some specific question (10k: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126176/would-like-to-gain-the-privileges-of-asking-questions-again), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125221/why-cant-i-post-this-question), or screen capture [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q3MEL.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U3PWm.png)) should not be edited to make them look better.

Comment: Nah, I'm referring to stuff that's blatantly off, but could use sprucing up because the writing is poor. I'd edit before closing otherwise of course

Answer (score 1):

If you think it can be salvaged to the point where it's an acceptable question, or if it's borderline, go ahead.

But if it's completely obvious that this is not a good fit for the site (i.e., can be immediately classified as off topic, too localized, etc.), and is not a migration candidate, then the ultimate fate of that question is, or at least should be, deletion.

Editing stuff that's going to be deleted anyway is a waste of your time, because:

- it's not going to stick around, so it doesn't need to be pretty; your time is better spent elsewhere
- if you suggest an edit, you're wasting the time of the people who review edit suggestions as well, and the +2 rep bonus will be revoked if the post is deleted anyway
- the site doesn't give you any recognition for it; edits on deleted posts don't count for badges, for example